# R: Get ranking of factor levels by group

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, levels

For now I have only the df with the columns `Number` and `Days`.

I want to get a ranking of the factor levels of `df$Days` in a separate column which is called `Ranking`.

```
    df <- data.frame(Number = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
                 Days = c(5,5,10,10,15,3,3,3,5,5,11,11,13,13,13),
                 Ranking = c(1,1,2,2,3,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,2))
```

My approach would be to group the data by Days and then mutate then the new column, but then I´m stuck how to assign the ranking to the new column

```
library(dplyr)
df_new <- df %>%
   dplyr::group_by(Days) %>%
   dplyr::mutate(Ranking = count(unique(levels(Days))) # This does not work obviously
```

Can you help me with that question? The code should work for any number of factor levels (could be up to 20 different Days)

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dplyr::dense_rank`, or `as.numeric(factor(Days, ordered = T))` in `base R`:

```r
df %>% 
  group_by(Number) %>% 
  mutate(Ranking = dense_rank(Days),
         Ranking2 = as.numeric(factor(Days, ordered = T)))
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 15 × 4
# Groups:   Number [3]
   Number  Days Ranking Ranking2
    <dbl> <dbl>   <int>    <dbl>
 1      1     5       1        1
 2      1     5       1        1
 3      1    10       2        2
 4      1    10       2        2
 5      1    15       3        3
 6      2     3       1        1
 7      2     3       1        1
 8      2     3       1        1
 9      2     5       2        2
10      2     5       2        2
11      3    11       1        1
12      3    11       1        1
13      3    13       2        2
14      3    13       2        2
15      3    13       2        2
```